# What is the antonym of opposite of "times/multiplied" in this case?

Tags: american-english, antonyms

> One can say that muscle is 3 times as dense as fat. [citation required]

What is the term for the opposite? Fat is 3 times less dense than muscle? That doesn't sound quite right. Is there a better way to say that?

Comment: relevant: http://www.nytimes.com/2007/10/28/opinion/28iht-edfreeman.1.8081659.html?_r=0

Comment: "3 times *more* dense" could be interpreted as "4 times *as* dense", although I suspect this is not the intended meaning.

Comment: @AndyT You're right. I reverted the question to my original wording.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree that 'three times less' sounds a bit confusing.

You could say:

> Fat is a third as dense as muscle.
>
> Fat has one third the density of muscle.

Comment: Of course! Multiply by a fraction. I don't know why that didn't occur to me.